# Applescript get last opened date of file

Tags: macos, file, applescript

I can use
`set modDate to the modification date of theFile as string` to get the last modified date of a file, and
`set modDate to the creation date of theFile as string` to get the date when the file was created.

Is there anything like `last opened date` to get the date when the file was last opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a UNIX command called `kMDItemLastUsedDate` that returns the date the target item was last used.

```
set the Last_opened_date to (do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemLastUsedDate " & quoted form of the POSIX path of theFile)
```

However, this command doesn't return a literal date object. Instead, it returns a date object in ISO 8601:2004 format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) which, if you try to put `date` before it, you'll get a syntax error.

Here is the revised script:

```
property months : {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}

set the Last_opened_date to date convert_date(do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemLastUsedDate " & quoted form of the POSIX path of theFile)

on convert_date(passed_data)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set the ISO_date to the first text item of (passed_data as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
    set the date_parts to every text item of the ISO_date
    set the_year to the first text item of the date_parts
    set the_month to the second text item of the date_parts
    set the_day to the third text item of the date_parts
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set the time_string to the second text item of (passed_data as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return item (the_month as integer) of months & the_day & ", " & the_year & space & the time_string
end convert_date
```

Comment: The revised script doesn't work. I think there are a couple of mistakes like missed spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i had the problem of wanting to get a date that was only available in the spotlight metadata (image file's content created date "kMDItemContentCreationDate" - original date from camera, i think). so i came up with this; note: i used "copy" and "tell" for my own clarity/ocd. there is an "as date" coercion for "do shell script" but it just gave me different errors. there is also simpler and better "awk"'s to do more/better things but the "- name " gives just the one mdls value you ask for.

(* gets the mdls value of "metaDate" ie one of the many available metadata dates
   "qpImg" is the "quoted form of posix path" of some file
   the awk strips it down to just the actual date/time string *)

```
tell current application to copy (do shell script ("mdls " & " -name " & metaDate & " " & qpImg & " | awk -F ' ' '/Date/ {print $3,$4};'")) to targDate
```

(* takes mdls info dates in form  "2012-01-19 14:37:38 -500" and makes it applescripty.
   "inText" is a posix path that is converted to it's "quoted form" on the fly.
   the "%x %r" is "standard numeric" date and 12hr time and can be coerced via "as date" *)

```
tell current application to set formtdDate to do shell script "date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' " & quoted form of inText & " +'%x %r'"
```

-- the two can be combined using xargs

```
tell current application to copy (do shell script ("mdls -name " & metaDate & " " & qpImg & " | awk -F ' ' '{print $3,$4};' | xargs -0 -I indate date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' indate +'%x %r'")) to targDate
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pure AppleScript solution to obtain a file's last access date. Using a combination of the shell tools [stat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) and [date](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) you can construct an AppleScript helper function that provides the last opened date:

```
on LastOpenedDate(theFile)
    set theStr to do shell script "date -r $(stat -f %a " & quoted form of (POSIX path of theFile) & ") +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    ISODateStrToDate(theStr)
end LastOpenedDate
```

The function uses the following helper function to convert the last opened time stamp which is returned as a [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.html) formatted string to an AppleScript date:

```
on ISODateStrToDate(theStr)
    set dt to (current date)
    set savedDelimeters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"-", "T", ":"}
    set {dt's year, dt's month, dt's day, dt's hours, dt's minutes, dt's seconds} to (every text item of theStr)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedDelimeters
    return dt
end ISODateStrToDate
```

The function `LastOpenedDate` can be invoked with an `alias`, `file` or `POSIX file` as an argument, e.g.:

```
LastOpenedDate(POSIX file "/var/log/system.log")
```

returns

```
date "Saturday, August 27, 2011 4:04:52 PM"
```

on my machine.

Comment: This is modifying the current date! What if the OP wanted to refer to the current date somewhere else in the program?

Comment: You can't modify the [current date](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW39).

Comment: Right... forgot about that. Sorry! :S

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get round to this...
I was doing other things and never had time to finish my cleanup script that I started.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions work properly on my Mac. I decided to find out - why? It turned out that the **mdls** shell command reads the result without taking into account the proper time zone. Or, it needs some additional help to do it, I don't know. (The solution where mdls is not used also does not work correctly for some reason).

I had to find a **AsObjC-solution** that gets the correct Date Last Opened (of file in Finder view) in any time zone & avoids other localization or date format hardcoding issues:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set posixPath to POSIX path of (choose file)

set theURL to (current application's |NSURL|)'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath
set mdItem to current application's NSMetadataItem's alloc()'s initWithURL:theURL
(mdItem's valueForAttribute:"kMDItemLastUsedDate") as date
```