# How to Check the Number of Times an Application has been opened on a Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I have a script that imitates the war games logon and I was hoping to track the number of times an application has been open, so that way the script doesn't run every time I open a new terminal. Rather I would like it to run when I reboot the machine and open iTerm for the first time since reboot. Is there a way to track the number of times an application has been open since reboot? That way I can write a condition for an if statement.

Comment: Last opened might be an option? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214410/applescript-get-last-opened-date-of-file

Comment: SO is for people having issues with code. Not sure it's the case

Comment: removed linux tag as this is a macOS question

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only execute once on boot, you could check for the existence (or not) of a specific file, and just touch it after it's opened for the first time, and delete it on shutdown or on startup before the full desktop/terminal window/environment loads in.